# R_List from a selected rows of matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a matrix and I want to create a list with selected rows of that matrix being the list elements.

For example this is my matrix

```
my.matrix=matrix(1:100, nrow=20)
```

and I want to create a list from this matrix such a way that each element of this list is part of the matrix and the row index of each part is defined by

```
my.n=c(1,2,4,3,5,5)
```

where `my.n` gives the number of rows that should be extracted from `my.matrix`. `my.n[1]=1` means row 1; `my.n[2]=2` means row 2,3; `my.n[3]=4` means rows 4 to 7 and so on.

So the first element of my list should be

```
my.matrix[1,]
```

second

```
my.matrix[2:3,]
```

and so on.

How to do it in an elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure, but I think you want something like this ...

```
S <- split(seq_len(nrow(my.matrix)), rep.int(seq_along(my.n), my.n))
lapply(S, function(x) my.matrix[x, , drop = FALSE])
```

Here we are splitting the row numbers of `my.matrix` by replications of `my.n`.  Then we use `lapply()` over the resulting list `S` to subset `my.matrix` with those row numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

```
end <- cumsum(my.n)
start <- c(1,(end+1)[-length(end)])
mapply(function(a,b) my.matrix[a:b,,drop=F], start, end)
```

`mapply` takes the first argument from two vectors and applies them to a function. It moves on to the second element of each vector and continues through each vector. This behavior works for this application to create a list of subsets as described. credit to @nongkrong for the `mapply` approach.

Comment: Thank you. I was doing something similar and almost got to this point. But I think using `split` before `apply` function as in @Richard Scriven is more elegant approach.